# Trying to setup provisioning profile, but device is locked

Tags: ios, xcode

Im trying to setup my iphone 5 for testing my app. Im using this guide;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment/ProvisionYourDevicesforDevelopment.html

Im at the step for provisioning my device, but when i connect the phone it says its locked, with this message:

The device is passcode protected.
Please unlock your device and reattach.

(0xE800001A).

I have disabled passcode protection, with no result.

NOTE: The phone has previously been used to test an app from another developer account.

Any suggestions?
Anders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are trying to install your app over the network. If yes, follow this:

- Disable Pass code.
- Go to Settings->Store->Apple ID->Sign out.
- Go to Settings->General->Profiles. Delete all the profiles that you see there, one by one.
- Switch of your iPhone and restart it.

On the other hand, if you are syncing via iTunes, here is another [interesting thread](http://forums.ilounge.com/ipod-touch/215463-anybody-get-error-message-0xe8000001.html) you may want to check out.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "over the network", but im simply trying to deploy and test an app on my phone, its the first time im doing this. I have tried the steps above, and it still does not work...

Comment: You must be either deploying the app via testflight over the Internet or via USB through your PC's itunes - which one? Or is it any other mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off both the "Passcode Lock" **and** the "Restrictions" passcode.